# How to install xen-tools and xen-server on Ubuntu 10.10

Tags: ubuntu, installation, xen

I'm trying to install xen.org server on a fresh Ubuntu server 10.10 installation.

When I try:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-xen-server
```

ERROR:

```
ubuntu-xen-server : Depends : xen-tools but it is not installable
```

and if I try:

```
sudo apt-get install xen-tools
```

ERROR:

```
Package 'xen-tools' has no installation candidate
```

Can you give me some advice?

Comment: When you say "no luck" an error would help.  What do you see if you enter `sudo aptitude search xen`?

Comment: thanks and sorry for the poor explanation. The search command gives me the ubuntu-xen-server package but not the xen-tools. I have also xen-hypervisor and xen-utils.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Xen 4:***

**Step 1:** Open a terminal and enter:

> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ukplc-team/xen-stable
>
> sudo apt-get update
>
> sudo apt-get install ubuntu-xen-server

Comment: While this will potentially solve OP's problem, it would be helpful to include a more explicit explanation of what your commands do.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried under [Ubuntu 10.10](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Ubuntu_releases#Ubuntu_10.10_.28Maverick_Meerkat.29) (Maverick Meerkat) to install Xen for virtualization. I was very surprised because APT-GET brought the message that the package "xen-tools" was not found.

I then looked in [Synaptic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synaptic_%28software%29), since the package was not available. In the package `xen-tools` sources have been either forgotten or replaced by a new package. In this case, the developer would then forget the dependencies to strip properly.

The experiment package from the Debian package management failed as well, because the version was too outdated there. Next, I was maybe on the Xen tools web page, and there I found a Debian package in version 4.2, which lied to install it without problems on Ubuntu 10.10. Here is the link to the website: http://xen-tools.org/software/xen-tools/releases.html there, and you download a package (Debian package: xen-tools_4.2-1_all.deb - 254k, MD5 e315aad0528784350134b0b517b70649) and install it. Then you can  install "ubuntu-xen-server" or "ubuntu-xen-desktop" problem via Synaptic or apt-get.

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu server 10.10 the xen-tools package is not available.

You can either install xen-hypervisor and xen-utils or try a completely different approach

using the [xen-cloud ISO](http://www.xen.org/products/cloud_source.html).

If your choice is the first one don't install an ext4 partition or you will find some extra troubles along the way.

Answer (score 0):

Here you find how to install xen-server on Ubuntu 10.10:

[Xen funktioniert unter Ubuntu 10.10, 10.04 nicht – gelöst](http://www.techdummie.de/index.php/betriebssysteme/linux/2621-problem-xen-funktioniert-unter-ubuntu-10-10-10-04-nicht-gelost/)

Comment: Deutch is not my mother tongue but I think I can get the overall meaning, if you understand it can you translate the main steps please?